# Regression model over factor levels using dplyr : getting repeated errors

Tags: r, dplyr, lm

I'm trying to run a logistic regression model over several factor levels in my dataframe and I'm getting replicated results for each factor level instead of a unique model's parameters.  It happens when I use the diamond dataset and run the same code, this:

```
diamonds$E <- 
  if_else(diamonds$color=='E',1,0)   #Make 'E' binary

fitted_models <- diamonds %>% 
  group_by(clarity) %>%              #Group by clarity
  do(model=glm(E~price,#regress price on E
           data=diamonds,
           family=binomial(link='logit'))) 

fitted_models %>% 
  tidy(model)%>% 
  View    #use broom package to look
```

I'm stuck as to why I'm having this particular issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your `glm` call. Remove `data=diamonds` and replace it with `data=.`.

```
fitted_models <- diamonds %>% 
  group_by(clarity) %>%              #Group by clarity
  do(model=glm(E~price,#regress price on E
               data = .,
           family=binomial(link='logit'))) 

fitted_models %>% 
  tidy(model)
```

whenever you are using `do` you need to reference the grouped data frame using `.`. As your code currently reads, you are referencing the original, un-grouped frame not the one passed to `do` by the pipe. for example, you cannot just call for the column `E`, you need to use `.$E`. An alternative solution would be `glm(.$E~.$price)`

Comment: thanks this worked.  I'd like to run about 20 ID's in the model.  Is this best way to do this by filtering the database with only the desired variables and running it?

Comment: @elliot That is likely the simplest. You can use the dplyr function `select()`. An alternative is to write out the formula separately and assign it to a variable, then use that in your function. This might be cleaner for you, especially if you want to change around the formula.

Comment: sorry to keep asking these follow-ups, but my approach to writing a formula variable in R  has halted me in my tracks.  I'm using paste to create a formula in my dataframe like this:

r <-paste(".$",colnames(data[-c(1,14,15)]),sep = "") %>% as.vector()
ID <-paste(r,collapse = "+") %>% as.vector()
formula <- paste(".$Promoter.score ~",ID,sep="")

I'm getting this error:Error in if (model) fit$model <- mf : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical

Any thoughts on why this might occur? Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry, but I won't take the time to parse the long string format there, but my best guess is that you need change your string into a formula. See `?as.formula`.